# jQuery Toggle, Hide & Change class

Tags: jquery

I feel sure this should already be covered here, but I haven't been able to track down a question that specifically deals with this.

I have 2 divs within a page, like this...

```
<div class="span4 section">
    ...content...
</div>
<div class="span8 section">
...content...
</div>
```

I need to implement an onclick that will hide the span4 div and change the class of the span8 div to span12, and after that has been done be able to revert it back (using jQuery.toggle, I assume).

I can successfully do one or the other, but can't get both things to work at the same time using my somewhat limited JS/jQuery knowledge!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should add another class name to you span8 class, e.g. `toggleSpan` and then

```
$('.clickElement').click(function () {
  $('.span4').toggle(); // this toggles only visibility
  $('.toggleSpan').toggleClass('span8 span12');
});
```

assuming that the element you want to use as trigger has the class `clickElement`

Answer (score 1):

You can use data attribute to help you with this. That should look something like this:

```
$('#target').click(function(event){
    if ($(this).data('toggled') == '1') {
        $('.span8').addClass('span12').removeClass('span8');
        $(this).data('toggled', '0');
    } else {
        $('.span12').addClass('span8').removeClass('span12');
        $(this).data('toggled', '1');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).toggleClass('span12 section');
$('.class="span4 section").hide();
```

call this function on click

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've already got that far, but as indicated in my question - I'm struggling to accomplish this along with hiding the span4 div

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/SwANP/

```
$('.section').click(function(){
   $('.section:eq(0)').toggleClass('span4');
   $('.section:eq(1)').toggleClass('span8 span12');
});
```